# A graph can be implemented as a list?

Tags: c, list, data-structures, graph

A teacher asked me to implement the Circle Line of the London Underground on the graphs class. As i see, the yellow line can be represented as a graph and also as a circular linked list.

[image: Circle line]

On my last graph algorithm i have created this struct:

`struct graph {
    int info;
    struct graph *edge[3];
};`

It's correct to implement the Circle Line graph like below? Or i would be making it a linked list instead of a graph?

`struct graph{
    int info;
    struct graph *next;
    struct graph *prev;
}`

Comment: A linked list *is* a graph (in the usual mapping of software to mathematics, where objects <=> nodes and pointers <=> edges). But you have a struct called `graph` which seems to represent a fragment of a (mathematical) graph. And you're asking whether it can represent the "Circle Line graph"... And what is a `no`?

Comment: Understood. I feared that implementing this graph like a doubly linked list would make it less of a graph, like it had to follow some rules. Sorry, the `no` was a typo.

Comment: *This* graph has the topology of a doubly-linked list. Not every graph is so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a circular doubly linked list like the 2nd suggestion you have. it easier I think as the first suggestion. but only if every object has 2 vertices.

linked list is a type of list btw.

If you have a variable amount of vertices you can just have a variable amount of pointers like this:

```
struct graph {
    int info;
    struct graph **edge;
};
```

and then allocate it to whatever amount you need, so for instance if you want to have a node with 6 edges you can just do:

```
struct graph my_graph;

my_graph.edge = malloc(6 * sizeof(my_graph *));
if (my_graph.edge == NULL) {
    // allocation error
}
```

from here you can connect the 6 edges to other objects.

Comment: Yes, but i can't understand where is the difference between a graph and a list in this case. Making a vector of edges is what defines it as a graph? Or it's ok to implement a next and prev pointer?

Comment: a doubly linked list is a graph with max 2 edges. you can have more if you want. just make a double pointer to `struct graph` and `malloc()` them to the amount of edges you need. see my updated answer.